# Why don't I get all available packets from apt?

Tags: raspbian, apt

I wanted recently to install profanity, a xmpp client, on my raspi. I ran a `apt-get update`, then a `apt-get dist-upgrade`, and tried to install the package. but it doesn't find it!
But on this link: http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/profanity/ the package is present!

This is my sources.list:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Why the package isn't available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the `control` files in the debian packages on archive.raspbian.org. It seems like this is a dependency problem. The package `profanity` depends on `libotr5` which depends on `libgcrypt20` which depends on `libc6` >= 2.15. But the available version of libc6 is 2.13.

I think, you should [file a bug with Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs).

Answer (score 1):

The archive carries packages for all versions of raspbian. profanity is available in jessie and stretch but not in wheezy.